# CentOS proxy server does not start: UFSSwapDir OpenLog error

Tags: centos, proxy, squid

I have tried almost anything to get running a squid proxy in CentOS7 with cache initialized at a non-default directory (which is usually /var/spool/squid).
I loaded a second disk for cache, it has been xfs partitioned and mounted at `/cache`.

Then, I created a "squid" directory inside the above directory which is supposed to receive all cached subdirectories.
Squid directory is owned by **squid**.
To avoid any permission issues, I also **chmod 777 recursevely** with command: `/cache`

**/etc/squid/squid.conf** is so setup:

- cache_dir ufs /cache/squid 1024 16 256
- cache_effective_user squid
- cache_effective_group squid

Launched `squid -z` command. It looks like hanging because it does not end with the # root@proxy: line.

When I check squid status I get always this error:

**UFSSwapDir :: OpenLog: Failed to open swap log.**

In `/cache/squid/` all directories seems to be there and **swap.state** as well. Everything is owned by squid with 777 permissions.

Any suggestion? Googled last 5 hours without finding anyone with this problem.

Thanks

Comment: Did you check for selinux AVCs? Try starting squid the run `ausearch -m avc -ts recent`

Comment: It is SELinux for sure, because I tried to disable it with ’setenforce 0’ command and it worked. I am looking for a way to get squid running without disabling SELinux because I prefer to have it on.

Comment: it’s most likely the location of the logs. You could set up a fcontext equivalency to make it work. https://danwalsh.livejournal.com/27571.html

Comment: Thanks, I did the trick by running this command: ‘semanage fcontext -a -t squid_cache_t /cache/squid’. Then I update with the ‘restorecon’ command.